# Meaningless negative votes

Tags: discussion, voting

Is there any mechanism to control (with penalty, restriction, suspension, rollback of some privileges,...) meaningless negative votes??

For example, today I encountered a situation which it seems someone appeared on a question page, downvoted question & all the answers (even the correct ones!!!!) without any explanation / reason / comment!!

I know downvoting costs two reputation points a vote! But it seems in some situations it's not deterrent enough. Is there any flagging option as users vote anonymously?

**After all, IMO, commenting & making the user aware of why he was downvoted would be very gentle & respectable. Silently downvoting some question/answer isn't helpful.**
*For example, today, in a similar situation, someone downvoted all in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587416/replace-multiple-characters-within-a-string-with-a-single-replace/42587519#comment72307272_42587519). But briefing the reason in a companying comment was very helpful for participants from educational POV, and I was grateful to him for his care*.

**Just a clarifying comment after every downvote can become a nice habit here on Stack Exchange as a part of our culture.**

Comment: I would like to control who gives positive votes, with penalty, restriction, suspension, rollback of some privileges. It gives 5 or even 10 rept a vote!

Comment: I downvoted your answer because the code within it is low quality.

Comment: @KevinB Question?  Or did you surmise the answer that prompted the OP to post here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588967/how-to-delete-all-td-in-specific-table-using-jquery/42589056#42589056]

Comment: So you think that answers that contain a serious security flaw in for example a sql statement that can take systems down and worse, shouldn't be down voted and any votes in those cases are meaningless? If that holds true, in which situations *are* downvotes then meaningful?

Comment: @rene: Assuming the answer linked by KebinB is correct, what is the security flaw in the posted example? My jQuery skills aren't that great...

Comment: @user000001 Pretty sure Rene's comment wasn't directed at that specific answer, but this meta question as a whole.

Comment: Updated the post. Try to be helpful & positive :-)

Comment: It's possible, since the question and all answers were down-voted that the voter thought the entire subject wasn't helpful to the community. If the question is worthless, how can any of its answers have value? Rhetorical, of course, but how the voter could be thinking.

Comment: @user000001 `$("table#deletealltd td")` jQuery selector has completely pointless "table" part. Whether it deserves downvote or not is open question (likely there is duplicate with much better answer - in this case I'd definitely downvote)

Comment: @user000001 my comment isn't in regard to the answer Kevin linked to. My comment and Kevin's need to be read as separate  examples of why this OP receives down votes.

Comment: *For example, today, in a similar situation, @Wiktor-Stribiżew downvoted all in this post* That is not correct, I did. Don't call out users for their down votes. It is toxic.

Comment: @rene Neither me nor anyone else doesn't consider someone who merely down votes a bad person !! Its evident with what I've said so far !!!! I'm talkin about  Wiktor-Stribiżew goodness! Its a misunderstanding by you, Take it easy

Comment: I haven't checked out the question in question, but I sometimes (rarely, in extreme cases) downvote blatantly lazy or super duper duplicate questions along with their answers if I get the impression they were given in less than good faith. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Downvoted on the main site and meta. Sad.

Comment: Monrning @NoName !

Comment: I have NOT downvoted a single answer in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587416/replace-multiple-characters-within-a-string-with-a-single-replace/42587519#comment72307272_42587519). [**Proof**](https://imgur.com/a/a752rtj).

Answer (score 16):

> Is there any mechanism to control (with penalty, restriction, suspension, rollback of some privileges,...) meaningless negative votes?

No.  SE has yet to invent a mind reading device (thank god) and so has no way of knowing if a vote cast is meaningless or meaningful.

There are some *very* rare circumstances in which SE will feel that there is sufficiently compelling evidence that votes were not cast based on the content of the post, and that's in situations involving serial voting.  In such cases the amount of votes, the time between them, the source of the votes, etc. can in some cases be so overwhelmingly compelling to indicate that the person is voting based on the person, not the post (basically, that someone went through and voted on each of someone else's answers without reading them) that they'll feel confident that the votes should be invalidated.  This of course isn't applicable to the situation you're describing though.

> For example, Today I encountered a situation which it seems someone appeared on a question page, downvoted question & all the answers(even the correct ones!!!!) without any explanation / reason / comment!!

Maybe they felt the answers *weren't* correct.  Or maybe they felt the answers weren't *useful*, even if they weren't incorrect.  If so, that's great, they're providing valuable feedback on the quality of the posts on the site.  If you disagree, you are of course free to reflect your own opinions through your own votes.

As SE has no mind reading device, as mentioned before, we have no actual way of knowing if the voter actually thought that the answers were useful and downvoted anyway.  That said, I would *very strongly* encourage you to not assume malice.  Unless you have *very compelling* reasons to think otherwise, you should assume that the voter sincerely felt that the answers weren't useful.

> I know down voting costs 2 rept. a vote!

It costs 1 rep; and that's only on answers.  The person whose post was voted on loses 2 rep.

> But it seems in some situations its not deterrent enough. Is there any flagging option as users vote anonymously

In my experiences it's way *too strong* of a deterrent.  I constantly see people who realize that a post is wrong, bad, or otherwise problematic, but will refuse to downvote it because that one Imaginary Internet Point means too much to them.

Heck, I even see people who want to go out of their way to downvote people out of spite that will only ever downvote their questions, and never answers, because the one point of rep lost by downvoting on answers isn't something they're willing to spend.  If anything the restriction needs to be removed so that low quality content will actually be indicated as being of low quality.

Comment: *"they felt the answers weren't useful, even if they weren't incorrect."* a classic example i tend to find is when an answer posts an answer with the OP's code with the fix and just says *"try this"*. even if the OP voted, accepted it and commented that it works i will downvote as not usefull because now i have to run both the OP's code and the answer's code, compare them and work out the cause and solution to problem myself rather than getting that from the answer

Comment: Well, SO needs to invent such a tool that would be trivial to construct that would identify users who downvote the question and then downvote every single answer below the question. It is a ridiculous situation where someone essentially throws a temper-tantrum because they don't like the question and then summarily downvotes technically correct answers below it. That user has a **close** vote to use if he doesn't like the question, the fact that they then get to stamp their feet and downvote every answer without penalty just invites more bad behavior. (wait till you are a parent...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Why do you believe that it's not possible for every answer to a question to not be useful?  Also note that downvotes are for answer that *aren't useful*, not for answers that aren't *correct*.  Lots of things can make a correct answer not be useful.  Serious problems with a question have a *very* high likelihood of making answers to it not useful.  *That's what makes them problems with the question.*  So poor questions are very likely to result in all answers not being useful.

Comment: Like I said, when the situation becomes so ridiculous that what's happening becomes a verb (`"@jww'ed"`), you have a problem. Example [How to rsync all folders present on the destination folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263543/how-to-rsync-all-folders-present-on-the-destination-folder)